# Search in JSON file

Tags: javascript

There is a JSON file, with a lot of nesting. How to correctly find what I needed, to extract the data on a key? If for example I need to get a name from this part:

```
"type": "SET",
"content": "(1 elem)",
"sub": [{
    "type": "SEQUENCE",
    "content": "(2 elem)",
    "sub": [{
        "type": "OBJECT_IDENTIFIER",
        "content": "2.5.4.3"
    }, {
        "type": "UTF8String",
        "content": "John Doe"
    }]
}]
```

Example file you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c1y59aqe/3/)

Comment: what do you want to search

Comment: 'content': 'John Doe' for example, now i write stupid solution for this, like this  var commonName = arrayJson[5].sub[3].sub[0].sub[1].content;

Comment: gone through your json... you have lots of content in it.. it is like nested and you need recursive function for it if you want entirely... so do you want entirely or particular?

Comment: two ways: 1) you need to know the object structure, than you can do as you are doing right now. 2)  there should be some condition like Object with type as "UTF8String" than `object .content` is the name. Once you know the consition than you can loop through the object properties and find required property

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply recursion logic to find the object.

```
function findObject(data, value){
  if( data.content == value ){
    return data;
  }
  else{
    for(var i = 0; i < (data.sub || [] ).length; i++ ){
      return findObject(data.sub[i], value);
    }
  }
}
```

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/c1y59aqe/8/)